# What does "this" refer to in JavaScript Parasitic Inheritance?

Tags: javascript

After years of creating applications using prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, I've started to explore using parasitic inheritance. Despite its primary pitfall - at least to me - of potentially creating several copies of methods in memory as you create an object hierarchy, I'm finding that it really resonates with me with its simplicity and the fact that "new" is rendered unnecessary. However, I'm stuck on what happens with "this." Most of the examples I've seen online only scratch the surface showing how to implement parasitic inheritance like so:

```
   function foo() {
       return {
          method1 : function() {...}
       }
   }

   function bar() {
       var that = foo();
       that.method2 = function() {
           //is "this" pointing to bar()?
       }
       return that;
   }
```

As I asked in the comment in the bar() object, does "this" refer to bar() or is the scope of this relegated to method2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick test indicates that `this` refers correctly to the object returned by `bar`:

```
function foo() {
    return {
        method1 : function() { return "spam" }
    }
}

function bar() {
    var that = foo();
    that.method2 = function() {
        return this.method1();
    }
    return that;
}

var b = bar();
b.method2(); // "spam"
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks! Now I can move forward. It's a bit of a conceptual leap, having done prototypal inheritance for so long. Parasitic inheritance is familiar, yet different enough where I'm admittedly a little uncomfortable - but that's a good thing! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `this context variable` in your `method2()` will be bound to the object, which gets returned from `foo()` pseudo constructor function. Every function (context) has a bound `this`, the value from the context variable, depends on the invocation from the method itself.

For instance, calling a function as property from an object (like you do there) will set the `this variable` to exactly that object. When you just call a function right away, its `this` is bound to the `global object` in ES3 and its `null` in ES5.

There are other methods and keywords which can change the value from `this`. Like `new`, `.bind()`, `.call()` and `.apply()`. But again, in your particular snippet here, `this` will be bound to the object which is stored in `that`.

Comment: Thought explanation, but what's ES3 and ES5?